# How can you use CSS variables with JavaScript to change images?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-variables

I'm working on a small update to http://codepen.io/wesbos/pen/adQjoY and wanted to use a CSS variable to change the image, just to see if I can do it. So far, it's not working.

```
<img src=imageFile>

<style>
:root {
    --image: 1;
    --imageFile: '"https://source.unsplash.com/7bwQXzbF6KE/800x500"';
}

img {
    src: var(--imageFile);
}
</style>
```

and I have some If, Then, Else, implemented in `<script> ... </script>` to change the `imageFile` variable.

In the DevTools console I get:

> GET file:///Users/tim/bloc/JavaScript30-master/03%20-%20CSS%20Variables/imageFile net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

The image doesn't change. Can you help? Here is my full code before the update:

```js
// get the inputs
const inputs = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.controls input'));

// listen for changes
inputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('change', handleUpdate));
inputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('mousemove', handleUpdate));

function handleUpdate(e) {
// append 'px' to the end of spacing and blur variables
    const suffix = (this.id === 'base' ? '' : 'px');
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`--${this.id}`, this.value + suffix);
}
```

```css
:root {
  --base: #ffc600;
  --spacing: 10px;
  --blur: 10px;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  padding: var(--spacing);
  background: var(--base);
  -webkit-filter: blur(var(--blur));
  /*  */
  filter: blur(var(--blur));
}

.hl {
  color: var(--base);
}

body {
  background: #193549;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'helvetica neue', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.controls {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

a {
  color: var(--base);
  text-decoration: none;
}

input {
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Update CSS Variables with <span class='hl'>JS</span></h2>
<div class="controls">
  <label>Spacing:</label>
  <input type="range" id="spacing" min="10" max="200" value="10">

  <label>Blur:</label>
  <input type="range" id="blur" min="0" max="25" value="10">

  <label>Base Color</label>
  <input type="color" id="base" value="#ffc600">
</div>

<img src="http://unsplash.it/800/500?image=899">

<p class="love">Made by <a href="http://twitter.com/wesbos">@wesbos</a> </p>
<p class="love">Chrome 49+, Firefox 31+</p>
```

Comment: So, the original image is hosted online but the replacement image you are trying to load is from your own local directory? That seems like the problem.

Comment: The `<img>` tag does not have a `src` CSS property. However, you could try with `background-image`.

Comment: @torazaburo: You can just set the src HTML attribute directly. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

`src` is an HTML attribute, not a CSS property.

`src=imageFile` points to a resource in the current URL directory path called `imageFile`. That's why the browser is attempting to `GET file:///Users/tim/bloc/JavaScript30-master/03%20-%20CSS%20Variables/imageFile`, which naturally doesn't work.

You can still use custom properties, but as you need to set an HTML attribute, not a CSS property, the `img` rule is not needed. Give the `img` an ID instead, remove the double nesting of quotes from your custom property value as they're not needed (not even in JavaScript), and set the value of the `src` HTML attribute to the custom property value directly:

```js
var customProps = window.getComputedStyle(document.documentElement);
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.id = 'imageFile';
img.alt = '';
img.src = customProps.getPropertyValue('--imageFile');
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

```css
:root {
    --image: 1;
    --imageFile: https://source.unsplash.com/7bwQXzbF6KE/800x500;
}
```

```html
<!--
The script should generate an img element that looks like this:
<img id="imageFile" alt="" src="https://source.unsplash.com/7bwQXzbF6KE/800x500">
-->
```

Some notes:

- I'm leaving the `--image` custom property in although it's unused in this example. I presume it's meant to be appended to the URL as query string data — which shall be left as an exercise for the reader.
- The ID is also technically unused in this example as I'm adding the element via JavaScript because it's not possible to mark up an `img` element without a non-empty `src` in a valid HTML document, but it will be useful when swapping out the image later as described in the question.
- In case anyone is wondering if using JavaScript for this sort of thing is a hack, it's not — the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/#syntax) itself explicitly lists JavaScript as a valid (even typical) use case for CSS custom properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use CSS to specify the source of your file you can use something like this:

HTML:

```
<img>
```

CSS:

```
img{
  content:url("IMAGE URL");
}
```

for your reference: https://jsfiddle.net/tqoLe7r3/

Comment: The OP would like to know how to make this work with CSS variables. See https://jsfiddle.net/tqoLe7r3/1/.

Comment: doesn't work for me in Firefox

Answer (score 0):

In your `:root` declaration, you can only set CSS values as variables.

Try this:

```
:root{
  --imageFile: url('https://source.unsplash.com/7bwQXzbF6KE/800x500');
}
img {
  content: var(--imageFile);
}
```

Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/wdkmbeL7/

Comment: "you can only set CSS values as variables" That's not true at all. See https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/#syntax In addition, the content property is not supported on anything other than ::before and ::after. Only some browsers support it, out of spec. I would not rely on it until after css-content-3 enters mainstream (which I'm not counting on happening within the next couple of years).

Comment: @surfmuggle it's working for me. It might be because I'm linking out to an image on Wikipedia.

Comment: I doubt that loading from wikipedia is the cause - see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4wcxe1ag/ - using `css-content` instead of the img-tag attribute src does not load the picture - at least not in chrome 75 nor in firefox 67.

Comment: It's working just fine for me in chrome 75. Here's what a screen shot of it looks like on my end. https://i23.photobucket.com/albums/b378/corrin_wyndryder/Screen%20Shot%202019-07-11%20at%2011.13.23%20AM.png