# ThemeService - better ways to change icons path on theme change?

Tags: angular, typescript

I've created theme change service for changing icons. In my theme service I've got BeaviourSubject for the icon's path - for light theme my icons are in the "assets/light-icons" and for dark one they're in the "assets/dark-icons" so in every component I'm injecting my service to a constructor. Depends on the chosen theme I'm passing folder name as a string to my Subject.

Example ts class:

```
constructor(public themeService: ThemeService) {}
```

Example html class:

```
<img [src]="'assets/'+themeService.functionWhichReturnsSubjectValueAsString+'/target_icon.svg'">
```

This solution works fine but I wonder whether you know a better solution. In this case I need to idject my service in every component I have icons/images. Is it possible to set this up from the parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can  also use css variables, but you need not give value to `[src]` else to  `[attr.src]`, see this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41350728/how-can-you-use-css-variables-with-javascript-to-change-images)

<strike>Futhermore, you need pass as SecurityTrustUrl.</strike> So imagine a styles.css like

```
body {
  --background-color: #fff;
  --text-color: #212a2e;
  --link-color: #543fd7;
  --url-path:'https://picsum.photos/'
}

body.dark {
  --background-color: #212a2e;
  --text-color: #F7F8F8;
  --link-color: rgb(130, 255, 161);
  --url-path:'https://dummyimage.com/'
}
body{
  color:var(--text-color);
  background-color:var(--background-color);
}
a{
  color:var(--link-color);
}
```

One component can be like

```
  customProps = window.getComputedStyle(document.body);
  constructor(public satinizer:DomSanitizer){}
  toogle()
  {
    document.body.classList.toggle('dark');
  }
  getImg(value:String)
  {
    return this.satinizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(
    this.customProps.getPropertyValue('--url-path').replace("'","").replace("'","")
         +value);
  }
```

And use

```
<img [attr.src]="getImg('200')">
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tkgcez?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**Update** Really it's not neccesary SecurityTrustUrl

Some like

```
 <img [attr.src]="'http://'+customProps.getPropertyValue('--url-path')+'200'">
```

where the properties are

```
--url-path:picsum.photos/;

//or 

--url-path:dummyimage.com/;
```